# Dynamically change value from a property file in Spring Boot Cucumber test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I have a Spring Boot application in which a specific bean (MyClass) gets a @Value annotated property whose value is defined in `application.properties` file:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    
  private String type;

  public MyClass(@Value("${type}") String type) { 
    this.type=type;
  }

  public String doSomething () {...} 
}
```

`application.properties` file includes the following: `type=typeA`

The testing is done using Cucumber, and I would like to test the behavior of the method `MyClass.doSomthing` when the value of `type` is not `typeA` but `typeB` ,
so I thought about doing the following:

The scenario in the `*.feature` file will start like this:

```
Scenario: Validating doSomething when type is B
    Given The value of type is typeB
    Then Validate doSomething
```

in the `*StepDef` file - the implementation of the `Given` step should somehow change the value of `type` to `typeB`, so that the flow of `MyClass.doSomthing` will process `typeB`:

```
@Given("The value of type is typeB")
public void changeTypeToB() {
    ...
}
```

My question is: How do I set the value of `type` to `typeB` (in the method `changeTypeToB`) considering the fact the during the test the Spring profile is the default one, hence the initial value of `type` is `typeA` ?

Thanks!

Dino

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively trying to change a configuration value after the Spring application has already started.

This generally requires starting a new application context and in Cucumber terms this means starting a separate test suite.

You would organize this like so:

```
package com.example.stepdefinitions;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  extraGlue = "com.example.app.config.typea"
)
public class RunCucumberTestTypeA {

}
```

And:

```
package com.example.stepdefinitions;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  extraGlue = "com.example.app.config.typeb"
)
public class RunCucumberTestTypeB {

}
```

Then use the context configuration to override the properties:

```java
package com.example.app.config.typeb;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "com.example.value=Hello", 
        "com.example.value2=World"
})
public class CucumberTestContextConfiguration {

}
```

Or enable a profile and put your properties in `application-type-b.yml`:

```java
package com.example.app.config.typeb;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("type-b")
public class CucumberTestContextConfiguration {

}
```

As a sanity check you can then verify if the right configuration is used in the `The value of type is typeB` step.

This is quite a bit of setup though. You can also create a new instance of `MyClass` that isn't managed by the spring application context and run your tests on that.

```java
@Given("The value of type is typeB")
public void changeTypeToB() {
    testInstance = new MyClass("typeB")
}
@Then("validate doSomething")
public void changeTypeToB() {
    testInstance.doSomething()
    // validate test instance did something
}
```

Finally you may want to reconsider your design. It sounds like `typeB` could be a feature toggle (because you want to change it at runtime) in which case using `@Value` wouldn't be the right approach.

Comment: Hi M.P. Korstanje,

Comment: Hi M.P. Korstanje, Thanks for the detailes answer! 
I tend to prefer your 2nd suggestion ("enable a profile and put your properties in application-type-b.yml"). The question is: 

Let's assume that the two profiles are defined (application-type-a.yml and application-type-b.yml) and I have two corresponding pairs of Cucumber feature & StepDef files.
Naturally I would like type-a.feature & type-a-StepDef to run with application-type-a.yml, 
and type-b.feature & type-b-StepDef to run with application-type-b.yml.
I guess it demands two @ActiveProfiles annotations... How do I configure that?

Comment: You organize the steps into different packages (one for a, one for b, one for everything that is common) and have different runners with different `@CucumberOptions` for each.